# How to get audio ducking in OSX?

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I'm developing a VoIP application for OSX and I want to support audio ducking of all other applications except mine when I'm in a call.

For iOS, the AVAudioSession handles this beautifully, but I can't seem to find an elegant solution for OSX. Right now, I'm using an AudioQueue to render audio, which gets mixed with audio from all the other running applications. Ideally, I want to ramp down all the other audio until the call is hung up, and then ramp all the other audio back up.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible on OS X; there isn't a good way control audio going to a device from other apps

Comment: I can't find the answer either, but I know it's possible because Skype is doing it. With iTunes playing, I placed a Skype test call, and the iTunes music ramped down nicely until the call completed.

Comment: I think Skype actually uses AppleScript or some other method for controlling iTunes' volume.  I tested with other audio players (Vox, Decibel) and their volume remained unchanged.

Comment: I think you are right. This time I watched iTunes as I made the call, and saw its volume slider drive down to 0, and then the player paused. When I hung up, it started the player and restored the volume. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The VoiceOver Utility has a setting to enable audio ducking - not sure if this is global to OS X or not though. Might be worth a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, sbooth. Your suggestion led me to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html.

This provides a great example for managing iTunes volume/player via the scriptingbridge framework.